# Why does returning an initializer list in a function returning a priority_queue call the vector constructor?

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```cpp
std::priority_queue<int> foo() {
    return {14, 12};
}
```

I would expect `foo()` to return a `priority_queue` containing 2 elements: 14 and 12. However, it returns a `priority_queue` containing 14 copies of 12. I stepped in with gdb and it appears that the `vector` constructor is being called. Could someone please explain why this is the case? Thanks.

**Edit:**
Also what would be the most idiomatic way of creating a `priority_queue` with 2 elements (or any number of elements) other than creating an empty one and inserting elements one by one (or is that the best option)?

Comment: What source do you base that expectation on?

Comment: It seems the most logical to me, although I realize, after looking at the spec, that this would never be the case.

Comment: Indeed :) In fact that version you copy pasted is invalid and [does not compile](https://godbolt.org/z/9P1bEToYs). Though it seems some versions of MSVC have a bug and accept it, with a broken result. That's probably what you stumbled upon.

Comment: @spectras Good to know. I couldn't make it compile either neither in gcc nor clang nor msvc: https://godbolt.org/z/aMasf9b1z

Comment: It compiles on [previous versions of gcc, clang, and msvc](https://godbolt.org/z/5EajWocKE) , just not the latest versions. Not sure why that is.

Comment: `std::priority_queue` is not a container it is a "container adapter". They wrap an underlying container in an interface. By default `std::priority_queue` wraps a `std::vector` which is why you see one being constructed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creating a `priority_queue` with two integers like that:

```
std::priority_queue<int> pq(a, b);
```

Was till recently treated by most compilers as legal, sending the parameters to the underlying container, thus creating a queue holding `a` times `b`. Although the constructor of `priority_queue` that is used for that is actually expecting two iterators:

```
std::priority_queue(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end);
```

Which is constructor #7 or #8 depending on the C++ version, as listed in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue

The arguments provided do not meet the `InputIterator` requirements.
And as it seems, most compilers fixed this issue recently and produce compilation error, see:
https://godbolt.org/z/Tqxdzc75d

It is interesting to note that the spec [[priority.queue]](https://eel.is/c++draft/priority.queue#priqueue.cons-4) uses the term `InputIterator`, but without clearly requiring the arguments to obey to  `InputIterator` requirements. Well as [cppreference does require that](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue) for constructors 7 to 9:

> Iterator-pair constructors. These overloads participate in overload resolution only if InputIt satisfies LegacyInputIterator.

It is quite clear that these constructors are meant for iterators, for example for use case like that:

```
std::vector<int> v(14, 12);
std::priority_queue<int> p(v.begin(), v.end()); // 14 times 12, now legit
```

Or, if you want two values - 14 and 12:

```
std::vector<int> v{14, 12};
std::priority_queue<int> p(v.begin(), v.end()); // 14, 12 - also legit
```

Bottom line: the original code shall fail compilation.

***EDIT***

It seems that the recent change is based on [LWG defect #3522](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#3522): *Missing requirement on InputIterator template parameter for priority_queue constructors* - this made the OP's code illegal and added the requirement for the `InputIterator` parameters to be actually iterators, already reflected in cppreference, as mentioned above.

Comment: That edit adding the exact defect reference is really the piece that was missing to have the full puzzle in one place. Great!

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I did a bit more investigation. I at first was confused about which `priority_queue` constructor I was calling since none of them seemed to make sense. Apparently constructor [#8](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue) is called which treats the two ints as iterators and calls `vector.insert(vector.end(), 14, 12)`. However, because they are ints, the `insert` call is overload [#3](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) instead of #4 which inserts n copies of x.

Answer (score 0):

You can see all the possible constructors for `std::priority_queue` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue).

Most of them are based on a pair of iterators.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/oGf6r4dqT)

```cpp
std::priority_queue<int> foo() {
    std::vector<int> ret{14, 12};
    return std::priority_queue{std::begin(ret), std::end(ret)};
}
```

Some others accept the underlying container as a parameter.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/Mb93sn7Eh)

```cpp
std::priority_queue<int> foo() {
    return std::priority_queue{std::less<int>{}, std::vector<int>{14, 12}};
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can declare a priority queue in your function body and use the `push` method to add your values and then return it.

Something like:

```
foo(){
    priority_queue<int> x;
    x.push(14);
    x.push(12);
    return x;
}
```

This also happens if you have not imported queue, as `priority_queue` is not a member of the `std` class.